# Why am I getting an SSL error in PHP even though I enabled the php_openssl.ext?

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, soap-client

I am running my PHP code off of XAMPP.  I am trying to connect to a WSDL form with a SoapClient object.  The error says I need to enable the php_openssl in my php.ini documents but I already have and it is still not working.  Here is the exact error:

> Warning: SoapClient::__doRequest(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\UI\SOAP\test.php on line 15
> SSL support is not available in this build

Is there anything else I need to enable on my php.ini?

Comment: there's multiple .ini files, you might have modified the wrong one. or perhaps the required .dlls can't be found. did you remember to restart apache after making the changes?

Comment: I modified both the production .ini and the development .ini.  I did restart apache when I made the change.  What other .dlls do you think are required?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the "extension_dir" directive is set to the right folder? Make sure to use an absolute path to that folder.